# MarkLogic - Sequential processing of XQuery statements

Tags: marklogic, marklogic-9, marklogic-dhf

I am running below code and expecting `insert-after` function to execute after `insert-before` function (at least with a 2000 millisecond gap) as my understanding is that XQuery would execute statements in sequence. But, after running the code, I see that both documents (*/content/testbefore.xml* and */content/testafter.xml*) created by the two functions have the exact timestamp value matching to the milliseconds.

How could I have the statements execute sequentially?

```
xquery version "1.0-ml";

declare function local:insert-before()
  {
  let $contents :=
    <book>
      <bookTitle>All About George</bookTitle>
      <tstmp>{fn:current-dateTime()}</tstmp>
      <chapter1>
        <chapterTitle>Curious George</chapterTitle>
      </chapter1>
   </book>
  return xdmp:document-insert("/content/testbefore.xml", $contents)
};

declare function local:insert-after()
{
let $contents :=
  <after>
    <bookTitle>All About George</bookTitle>
    <tstmp>{fn:current-dateTime()}</tstmp>
    <chapter1>
      <chapterTitle>Curious George</chapterTitle>
    </chapter1>
 </after>
 return xdmp:document-insert("/content/testafter.xml", $contents)
};

local:insert-before(),
xdmp:commit(),
xdmp:sleep(2000),
local:insert-after();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`fn:current-dateTime()`](https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions-31/#func-current-dateTime) is [deterministic](https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions-31/#dt-deterministic), and will always return a consistent answer within the same transaction.

> [Definition] A function that is guaranteed to produce ·identical· results from repeated calls within a single ·execution scope· if the explicit and implicit arguments are identical is referred to as deterministic.

You could use [`xdmp:elapsed-time()`](http://docs.marklogic.com/xdmp:elapsed-time), which will return an `xs:dayTimeDuration` of the elapsed time since the start of processing of the query, and add that to the `fn:currentDateTime()` value:

```
<tstmp>{fn:current-dateTime() + xdmp:elapsed-time()}</tstmp>
```

Answer (score 1):

The statements execute in that order, but everything is committed to the database in the same snapshot.